# Global variables undefined when referencing them via window object

Tags: javascript, reference, window, undefined

I'm fairly new to declaring variables globally via *window*, so I was a bit surprised that the following snippet behaves differently depending on the browser.

```
window.test = "Good";
document.write(window.test);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(window.test);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(test);​
```

**Firefox, IE, Opera**

> Good
>
> undefined
>
> Good

**Chrome and Safari**

> Good
>
> Good
>
> Good

My initial belief was that it should behave the way Chrome and Safari does, but I realize I might not have a proper understanding of the *window* object, so would anyone more knowledgeable explain this?

I realize I can just use `var test = "Good";` for that scope, but I'm interested in why the browsers handle it differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/WHYFc/

Comment: Something else to test is using `window["test"]` in place of `window.test`, but I'm sure those results will be the same.

Comment: What if you use `window.test` the third time?

Comment: I did test `window["test"]` but the results were the same. Using `window.test` any time other than the first returns _undefined_.

Comment: *I'm fairly new to declaring variables globally via window* -> you'd better keep it that way. http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/

Comment: It's because you're using `document.write()` after the document has loaded. Your fiddle is set to run the code `onload`, but FF will give you "good good good" if you run the code before that: http://jsfiddle.net/WHYFc/2/ or if you run `onload` but don't use `document.write()`: http://jsfiddle.net/WHYFc/1/ (noting that jsfiddle puts your JS code in an `onload` handler by default; you can change this via the drop-down on the left). `document.write()` is almost always the wrong choice...

Comment: Haha how about never use `document.write`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle is using window.load to create the script.

document.write after load CLEARS/WIPES the document so what you are seeing is normal for those browsers and webkit simply is more lenient

Here is the code you produce in jsfiddle:

```
window.addEvent('load', function() {
window.test = "Good";
document.write(window.test);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(window.test);
document.write('<br>');
document.write(test);
});
```

Change your fiddle to head or body and it will work as expected

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/GcwdE/)

Comment: That seems to be the answer. I was experiencing issues in a Greasemonkey script where I had to use window.ABC instead of ABC after declaring window.ABC within the scope, and I went ahead and stripped it down to bare essentials to ask about here, but I guess I didn't anticipate this happening.

Comment: document.write is tricky that way. Many people are surprised when they refactor some working code into a function, call it onload and the page breaks. Instead use innerHTML or jQuery .html() or .text

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store something globally even though you're opening new documents, you could (kind of ironically) use the `document` object, which seems to be persistant.

```
document.test = "Good";

document.write(document.test); // > "Good"
document.write('<br>');
document.write(document.test); // > "Good"
document.close();

setTimeout(() => {
    document.write("Also " + document.test); // > "Also Good"
    document.close();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I've learned a lot since this question and I avoid globals now and use IIFEs for pretty much everything but debugging now.